# Docker LVM support

Tags: docker, volume, shared, lvm

I have two docker continers in privileged mode. And I installed LVM software in both. Its working fine, but the problem is when I create any volume group or logical volume in one disk suppose /dev/sdd1, I am not able to see into another container those volume groups. I am able to mount /dev/sdd1 in both.

Answer (score 0):

It may be LVM-related problem.
Try to point at your PV (or VG) in second container manually: `pvscan`, `vgscan /dev/sdd1`

Also, LVs inside second container may be disabled
Commands to show them: `lvs -a`, `lvdisplay -a`
Last one useful to determine **LV Status**
So, enable it if not: `lvchange -ay <VG name>/<LV name>`

PS: please be specific. What `not able to see` means?